# не получается синхронизировать потоки

Tags: android, rest, синхронизация

день добрый
пишу приложение, которое бегает за json строкой к rest сервису
из активити согласно MVP запрашиваю информацию у презентера, а он дергает через api сервис
activity:

```
   @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_crypto);
    recyclerViewRatesInfoActivity = findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewRatesInfoActivity);
    FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
    //loadingIndicator = findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);

    if (presenterCrypto == null)
        presenterCrypto = new PresenterCrypto(this);

    if (listOfRates == null) {
        listOfRates = new ArrayList<>();
        listOfRates = presenterCrypto.getDefaultData();//вот тут вызываю метод с запросом
        Log.d(TAG, "listOfRates == null ? " + (listOfRates == null));
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "listOfRates = " + listOfRates.toString());
    recyclerViewRatesInfoActivity.setHasFixedSize(true);
    cryptoAdapter = new CryptoAdapter(listOfRates);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
    recyclerViewRatesInfoActivity.setAdapter(cryptoAdapter);
    recyclerViewRatesInfoActivity.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

presenter:

```
@Override
public List<Crypto> getDefaultData()  {
    cryptoApi.getFullListCrypto();//если вставить сюда thread.sleep(2000); то все ок
    Log.d("CryptoApi", "presenter`s field 'list' after execute request = " + list.toString());
    Log.d(TAG, "list.size sending from presenter = " + list.size());
    return list;
}
```

и собственно сам класс для запроса через ретрофит

```
public class CryptoApi implements ICryptoApi {//это класс для нашей модели model
private final String TAG = "CryptoApi";
private final String BASE_URL = "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/";
public ICallBack iCallBack;
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build();

public CryptoApi() {
}

public CryptoApi(ICallBack iCallBack) {
    this.iCallBack = iCallBack;
}

@Override
public void getFullListCrypto() {
    ICryptoService iCryptoService = retrofit.create(ICryptoService.class);
    Call<List<Crypto>> call = iCryptoService.getAllCryptoCurrenciesRates(10, null);
    doNetworkCompuation(call);//увожу выполнение из основного треда

}

private void doNetworkCompuation(Call<List<Crypto>> call) {//переводим исполнение запроса в другой поток и обрабатываем ответ
    new Thread(() -> {
        try {
            List<Crypto> listOfCrypto = new ArrayList<>();
            Response<List<Crypto>> response = call.execute();
            if (response.body() == null)
                Log.d(TAG, "response == null? " + (response.body() == null));
            else {
                Log.d(TAG, "response.body() in CryptoApi = " + response.body());
                listOfCrypto = response.body();
                iCallBack.callingBack(listOfCrypto);//этот интерфейс  написан после рыться в форумах но и от него результата нет
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "something wrong in doNetworkCompuation" + e.toString());
        }
    }).start();
}
```

}

пробовал через call.enqueue и возвращать полученный json через onReponse() - но результат тот же. по логам вижу, что строка от сервера приходит, какой она и ожидается, но на полторы-две секунды позже, чем информация считывается

Answer (score 0):

Предположу что тут косяк с потоками из-за использования Retrofit, насколько я помню при его создании открывается поток, а вы делаете поток в потоке

```
ICryptoService iCryptoService = retrofit.create(ICryptoService.class);
```

В строчке выше ошибка